# ReactJS: aggregate CSS classes

Tags: css, reactjs

Suppose I have some CSS class defined as:

```
.fg-dark-color {color: #444;}
.bg-dark-color {background-color: #444;}
.fg-light-color {color: #fff;}
.bg-light-color {background-color: #fff;}
```

I would like to aggregate those classes into groups like:

```
.btn {
   .fg-dark-color;
   .bg-light-color;
}

.btn-reversed {
   .fg-light-color;
   .bg-dark-color;
}
```

And when I have reactjs component like:

```
var Btn = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
       <button className='btn'>My button</button>
    );
  }
});
```

I want the class name `btn` be automatically expanded to `fg-dark-color bg-light-color`

Is there any reactjs tools support of doing that? Or if there is no off-the-shelf tool available how can I do it in react in a generic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've come up with my own solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/expjs

Usage:

```
var ExpJs = require('expjs');
// the rules could be managed centrally in another js file
// in which case it would be: var rules = require('css_rules');
var rules = {
    'btn': 'fg-color-dark bg-color-light',
    'btn-reverse': 'fg-color-light bg-color-dark',
    ... 
}
var exp = ExpJs.init(rules);

var Btn = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
       <button className={exp('btn-reverse btn-my-button')}>My button</button>
    );
  }
});
```

The above code will output the following html:

```
<button class='fg-color-light bg-color-dark btn-my-button'>My button</button>
```

Comment: isn't `exp('btn-reverse')` just `rules['btn-reverse']` ?

Comment: `exp('btn-reverse') === rules['btn-reverse']` but `exp('btn-reverse classa classb') != rules['btn-reverse classa classb']`

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames), a module [officially supported](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html) by React.

According to what you wrote, you could write for example:

```
var btn = [
   fg-dark-color,
   bg-light-color
]
```

and then:

```
return (
   <button className={classNames(btn)}>My button</button>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get this kind of effect, you can write your classes as Javascript objects and combine with a utility function:

```
m: function() {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i]) {
            for (k in arguments[i]) {
                result[k] = arguments[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;  
}
```

For more pointers for CSS in React I suggest Christopher Chedeau's fantastic [slide deck](https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js) on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the slide deck, love it and give you an up ;-). BTW I've come up with my own solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) to create blueprints of css you want, then you can just apply them as

What is even better is that classNames is allowing you to use conditionals.

```
let setActive = (isActive) => {
    return classNames({
        active: isActive
    });
};
```

Then you can use it as:

```
<Element className={setActive(true)} />
```

Comment: This is not a solution to my question